# Ho to display unique values in the angular material drop down?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I am trying to display options for the select by using angular material as shown below.

where appitem is list of array.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select app" formControlName="appControl" required> 
      <mat-option *ngFor="let app of appitem" [value]="app.appname">
                {{app.appname}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

But here app.appname contains duplicate values, where I want to display only unique values.

could you any one help on this.

Answer (score -1):

Well instead of putting in the material you can filter out your array to be unique like this -

```js
var myArray = ['5', 1, '6', 8, '1'];
var unique = myArray.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i); 

console.log(unique);
```

where unique would be

```
['5', 1, 6, '8']
```

Comment: your example is wrong, myArray is already unique (1 and '1' are different), and the output of this snippet would be: ["5",1,"6",8,"1"]